# How to debug particular async method, when runnig several async methods in parallel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, async-await, visual-studio-debugging

Look at this sample code:

```
class Program
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();

    static async Task TaskBody()
    {
        var counter = Random.Next(100);

        while (true)
        {
            counter += Random.Next(100);
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Counter = {counter}");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var _ = TaskBody();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Suppose, that one need to debug this code (e.g., `while` body).
The obvious way is to hit breakpoint somewhere:

[image]

But since there are 10 asynchronous methods running in parallel, debugger will stop at *each* method.

What if one wants to debug only particular method?

The most obvious is to set some breakpoint condition.
These things were considered as conditions:

- `ThreaId`. Doesn't fit async methods, since thread can be changed after  `await`.
- `TaskId`. Can be (and will be in this sample) `null`.
- `AsyncLocal<T>` local variable. `AsyncLocal<T>.Value` can't be used in breakpoint condition, since it leads to native method call, and this is not allowed.
- `TaskBody` signature changes. E.g., pass some "Id" on scheduling (in the sample most obvious way is to pass `i` from calling method). This will work, but requires unnecessary changes for debugging purposes only.
- Another local variable (e.g. `Guid`) as "method Id". This will work and looks as the best option, but still is the trick.

I know about `Threads`, `Tasks` and `Parallel Stacks` debug windows.
In fact, the question is being asked after quick reading of [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164746.aspx) guide.

Can this be achieved without tricks and hacks, using VS2015 capabilities only?

Comment: Conditional Breakpoint or add a variable and add if...

Comment: "Conditional Breakpoint" - yes, the question is what to write as the condition.

Comment: ManagedThreadId : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.managedthreadid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @x...: thread Id can be changed during async method execution. Parts of async method can be executed on different threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way would be to either use something like Debug.WriteLine() and output whatever you need, or much better, pass some value to the Thread/Task, (some sort of ID) and then just set a conditional Breakpoint where ID==Thread#

e.g. you start your threads with IDs from 1-10 and you want to Debug Thread#5

Conditional Breakpoint with ID == 5

I hope this works :)

EDIT: I think the latter one is what you said in your Question however I think that this is the best solution, and a ThreadID shouldn't hurt unless you've got a LOT of threads.